# nyroModal Set Focus

Tags: jquery, nyromodal

Using nyroModal I have setup a modal window with some text boxes. This window pops up on page load. I need focus to be set to the first text box. I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$.nmManual('pageToLoad.html'});

$.fn.nyroModal.settings.endShowContent = function(elt, settings) {
    $('input:text:first', elt.content).focus();
};
...some more code here...
});
```

There isn't much documentation for the endShowContent, so hopefully someone here can lend me a hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i found from docs of nyroModal it should called by:

```
$.nmManual('pageToLoad.html',{callbacks: {afterShowCont: function() {}}}
```

Comment: and also - may be better to have wrapper class for nyro generated content ? $('.nyroclass input:text:first')

Comment: That worked. However, i tried $('.nyroclass input:text:first')... and that caused the window to not appear at all. Where in the docs did you find that? I've been reading over everything i can find on the site and couldn't find that one. Thank you so much.

Comment: i meant by .nyroclass - some your own class that wrap pageToLoad.html, docs are there: http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/

Answer (score 0):

The right code should be:

```
$.nmManual('pageToLoad.html', {
  callbacks: {
    afterShowCont: function(nm) {
      nm.elts.cont.find('input:text:first').focus();
    }
  }
});
```